# Problems With php contact form..is it my code or my server settings?

Tags: php, forms, contacts

iv been trying to build a php contact form and am not getting the desired results, can anyone tell if the following code would work on there servers or if its the code at falt?

contact.php

```
<form name="contact" action="contactMail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table id="contactTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="contactTable"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
                        <td><input name="name" id="name" type="text" size="30" required="required"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="contactTable">Subject</td>
                        <td><input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" size="30" required="required" ></td
                    ></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="contactTable"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
                        <td><input name="email" id="email" type="email" size="40" required="required" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="contactTable" valign="top"><label for="message">Message</label></td>
                        <td><textarea id="message" name="message" required="required" ></textarea ></tr>
                </table>  
                <div align="center">  
                 <input id="blueButton" type="reset" value="Clear All">
                 <input id="blueButton" type="submit" value="Send Message">
            </div>    
            </form>
```

contactMail.php

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "example@hotmail.co.uk";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
header ("refresh:2;url=contact.php");
?>
```

Comment: You need to let us know what results you are getting, why they aren't the desired results and what the desired results should be. Also, I've never seen a `refresh:2;url=<url>` header before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on a number of things - firstly, you've not stated what your "desired result" is, and you've not explained what is happening.

However, my assumption is that you want:
1/ The email to send
2/ The message "Thank you!" to be displayed to the user 
3/ After 2 seconds, the user is redirected to a new page:

As such, your main problem is your header - you can't send a header after sending output to the browser (which is what echo()) does, so your header() won't be sent.

As such, you need to swap the lines over:

```
header ("refresh:2;url=contact.php");
echo "Thank You!";
```

Comment: No problem - if this has solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give either from email or to email  as domain email.
example: if 'xxx.com' then 'xxx' is your domain name so your domain email something like demo@xxx.com